# Need some help on basics of excel-VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am interested in counting a variable (male) in column A and another variable (working) in column B. I want the output to be the total number of times both 'men' and 'working' are displayed together. 
Any help is highly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: [`COUNTIFS` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842)

Comment: **=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A100="male"),--(B1:B100="working"))**

Comment: @VBasic2008 A `countifs` should perform faster than `sumproduct`.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: I truly hope so, it's just an alternative, so I didn't put it as an answer. I'm still using Excel 2003. If you think it's inappropriate, I'll remove it.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Actually still using Excel 2003 is indeed inappropriate, please remove it ;) • I was telling the downside just in case anyone would consider to use this as an equivalent to countifs (which is available since 2007). So might be worth to keep it as alternative for some old-fashioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following data

[image]

#### VBA solution

Use the [WorksheetFunction.CountIfs method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.countifs). The following code should return `4`:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CountMaleWorking()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(ws.Columns("A"), "male", ws.Columns("B"), "working")
End Sub
```

#### Or just use a forumla

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"male",B:B,"working")
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
A quick follow up question, how do I save the count in a new column?

Comment: Write the value to a cell `ws.Range("E5").Value = …` or use the formula.

Answer (score 0):

As GSerg mentioned, no vba but a simple countifs.

Put in C1

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A100,"male",B1:B100,"working")
```